# Unknown source of high number of connections

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, connectivity, connections, aws-aurora

In MySQL/Aurora I see from time to time a spike in connections number (from about 100 to 4000):
[image]

MySQL [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections) says:

> Connections
>
> The number of connection attempts (successful or not) to the MySQL server.

So I was thinking those coming from failed connection, however I don't see failures:

```
MySQL [(none)]> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS like 'Conn%';
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name                     | Value    |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
| Connection_errors_accept          | 0        |
| Connection_errors_internal        | 0        |
| Connection_errors_max_connections | 0        |
| Connection_errors_peer_address    | 0        |
| Connection_errors_select          | 0        |
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap         | 0        |
| Connections                       | 34388970 |
+-----------------------------------+----------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> show global variables like '%conn%';
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name                                 | Value             |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| aurora_max_connections_limit                  | 16000             |
| connect_timeout                               | 10                |
| disconnect_on_expired_password                | ON                |
| init_connect                                  |                   |
| max_connect_errors                            | 100               |
| max_connections                               | 4000              |
| max_user_connections                          | 0                 |
| performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size | 512               |
+-----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

I would very much like to understand what those are and when they are coming from.

Comment: A good way to understand where the connections are coming from is to look at the flow log for your Aurora instance.

Comment: Yeah I was looking on those, got me to the source server but still looking for the source script :D

Answer (score 0):

- Sounds like a hacker.
- Based on your graphs, I suggest that `max_connections = 4000` is unreasonably high.  It looks like 20 might be reasonable.
- You might want to set `max_user_connections` to some reasonable value (instead of `0` for "unlimited").

Comment: Unfortunately it won't tell me the source of those connections.

Comment: Look for TCP tools.